# Is there difference in common usage between 'I have an answer' and 'I know an answer' sentences

Tags: differences, word-usage, questions

In common everyday usage is there any diffrence between these sentences:

1. 'I have an answer'

   and
2. 'I know an answer'

My clue:
Ad 1. I have some proposition of an answer but I'm not 100% sure
Ad 2. I know what the exact answer is.

Comment: Any difference between *have* and *know* is dwarfed by the one between *an* and *the*.

Comment: My mistake - should be 'an' everywhere - question corrected.

Comment: I'd say that 'I know an answer' is not all that common; [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+know+an+answer%2CI+have+an+answer%2CI+have+the+answer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20know%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20the%20answer%3B%2Cc0) seem to support that. 'I have an answer' is often used in the 'reply' sense though, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question,

"**In common everyday usage** is there any difference..."

Answer: there is no difference.

You could say that "have" is a little more weak/polite tone of voice; "know" is a little more decisive/strong.  (If you wanted to be "more polite, less decisive" you'd go on to something like "May I suggest...")

---

**Note 1** as Edwin points out, "I know an answer" is less common.

**Note 2** Just to be crystal clear.  Your two clues, are indeed, completely wrong. Both sentences are equally as "certain"

**Note 3** Nothing to do with your question, but as tchrist points out, you may be thinking more of the difference between "the answer" (implies there is only one) and "an answer" (implies there are more than one answers).  **Note that** if you use "an" or "the" is **unrelated** to, whether you use "have" or "know".  Again there is no difference between "have" or "know".

Answer (score 1):

There can be a difference between *have* and *know*, especially with regard to game shows or teaching. In these cases, *having* an answer doesn't necessarily imply knowledge of an answer. The host or teacher may ask:

> May I *have* an answer?

Which of course is the proper question as the host is soliciting a response to his question.  Whether he has knowledge of the answer or not, the host is requesting transfer of information rather than obtaining knowledge. It can be reasonably assumed that the one who asks the question has the answer, either because it's written before him or that he otherwise may have knowledge of the answer.

The response from a contestant/student will likely be:

> I *have* an answer.

While it's possible that the answer is known by the respondent, the possibility exists that the answer may not fully comply with the question being asked.

Note that this is a one-way difference. If one *knows* an answer, he *has* an answer. However if one *has* an answer, it may just be a guess and not knowledge.